# How can I use an Action to move down to the next path in the layers window?

Tags: action, adobe-illustrator

I did a gray scale image trace and came back with 250 colors.  I created an action that selects the same fill color and then groups them together.  Every time I want to run the action I have to select the next target in the layers window.  Is there anyway to tell the action to move to the next target or path in the layers window until there is no more to do?  I Tried select next object, but it doesn't work on paths or targets.

Thank you,
Amber

Comment: Have you tried to record your action with `Select -> Next Object Below` instead of clicking on an object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I figured out my problem.  I was trying to use the select next object below inside a group.  I guess you can't do that, it has to be inside a layer.